# Why is my SQLite database file not showing any data?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, react-native

Aim -

I am trying to store longitude and latitude data from the geolocation API using React native. I created a `.db` file put it into the `/assets/` folder in android. First, instead of the location data, I am trying to insert or retrieve any kind of data.
ERROR -

It shows that there is no table named `Test` when I try to `console.log()` it.

Problem -

Whenever I try to insert data into the database I don't see any new data added and also When I try to read an already populated database I see nothing. Where am I wrong? I am fairly new to this.

1. What is the response returned by the `SQL transaction`. I `console.log` it but couldn't understand.
2. Where should be the `transaction function be located?`

I am using DBbrowser for SQLite
OS - MacOS

CODE -

```
I am using this function to send or receive data.

sendData = () => {
        // var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')
        var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: 'a', createFromLocation : "~test.sqlite"}, this.openCB, this.errorCB); 
        db.transaction(txn => {
        txn.executeSql(
        //   "INSERT INTO Test (latitude,longitude) VALUES(?,?)",
        'SELECT * FROM Test',
          [],      //Argument to pass for the prepared statement
          (res) => {
            // let row = res.rows.(1);
            console.log(res);
          }   //Callback function to handle the result response
        );
      }); 
    };

// I mapped this button to send data.

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.sendData} style={styles.button}>
<Text> SEND DATA</Text
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to modify a database stored in the assets folder.  The typical method is before ever trying to open the database to insert records, you first check to see if the database exists in your apps data folder (not sure if React has the same folder structures or not).  If the database doesn't exist in the data folder, then you copy your clean database from assets to the data folder, then open the database from the data folder.  As long as the app isn't deleted off the device, the database in the data folder will persist, along with all of the data you have inserted into it.  Once the app has been deleted and reinstalled, the database will have to be copied from assets once again and will be clean, with no new data in it.

I don't know if the same data folder structure applies to React, but in native Android I use:

```
 "/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/databases/"
```

OR

```
DB_PATH = myContext.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath() + "/databases/";
```

Comment: Which data folder can you please specify?